# Create Report With One Group In SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

Please Consider this report that built using Table:

[image]

I want to create such this report but my report is like this:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Seems issue with details rows of Table structure. Can you please re-create same table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, Please remove your current table and add it again.

Create row group like below,

[image]

So Table should be look like below,

[image]

Now, run by making necessary changes.

It works perfectly as per expected result.

[image]